# check existance of an implementation, for a "string search method in database"

Tags: c#, database, algorithm, optimization

I am developing an application which receives packets from network and stores them into database. in one part, I save dns records to db, in this format:

1. IP Address(unsigned 32bit integer)
2. DNS record(unlimited string)

The rate of DNS records, is about 10-100 records per second. As it's realtime, I have not enough time to check for duplicates by string search in database. I was thinking of a good method to get a unique short integer (you say,64 bit) per given unique string. So my search, from string search, becomes number search and lets me check for duplicates faster. Any idea about implementations of what I told, or better approaches is appreciated. samples in C# are preferred. but any good idea is welcomed.

Comment: What about not storing the DNS record as text? You could parse the records and avoid most of the string searching. But it's really hard to suggest anything concrete without knowing what you're actually trying to do - I don't see how "checking for duplicates on insert" is incompatible with soft real-time, especially with something like DNS records. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521148/string-to-unique-integer-hashing), talking about hashing strings into integers, and since addresses are pretty long (letter wise), I would use some modulo function to keep it in integer limits.

The results would be checked with a hash table for duplicates.

This could be done for the first 20 letters, and then the next 20 for a nested hash table if required and so on.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you set up your table-indexes and Primary Keys in the table correctly.
- Load the table contents asynchronuosly every couple of seconds and populate a generic `dictionary<long,string>` with it.
- Perform the search on the dictionary as it is optimized for searches. If you need it even faster, use a hashtable.
- Flush the newly added entries in a Transaction asynchronuosly into the DB.

P.S. Your Scenario is to vague to create a decent code example.