# how can i get fix random number as taking input name in javascript

Tags: javascript

Actually, I want a fixed number at a string like love calculator help me find out this problem.
The Brandon number should not change the same name, I type the same name so I should get that same number. Give me some hint or code. In javascript .

Comment: You want something like a hash. You can convert every character to a code point and combine them in whatever way you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the same '*random*' output when the same input is given, you are looking for a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Something like this:

```js
function hashCode(string) {
    let hash = 0;
    if (string.length == 0) {
        return hash;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        let char = string.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
        hash = hash & hash;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

In the snippet below you should be able to see that **as long as the same string is inputted, the same number will be outputted.**

```js
function hashCode(string) {
    let hash = 0;
    if (string.length == 0) {
        return hash;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        let char = string.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
        hash = hash & hash;
    }
    return hash;
}

let input = document.querySelector("#input")
let output = document.querySelector("#output")

input.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  output.value = hashCode(input.value)
})
```

```html
<p>Enter text here</p>
<input type="text" id="input">

<p>'Random' number outputted here</p>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="" id="output">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourName = document.getElementById('inputName').value;

// Returns a random integer from 0 to 99:
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

var nameWithRandomNumber = yourName.concat(randomNumber);
```

Comment: *"I type the same name so I should get that same number"*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the same output for the same input, it is not random.
What you are looking for, is a hashing function.

Depending on your requirement (length, uniqueness/collisions) this can be helpful:
[String to unique integer hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521148/string-to-unique-integer-hashing/16521671)